# SQL Error on Sales Order Screen After Applying Supee-6788 Patch

Tags: mysql, database, magento, patch

After applying the patch, I get this issue when loading the orders screen:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:783:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'IFNULL(at_prX_status.value, def_at_prX_status.value)' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table`
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_item` AS `auit_oit` ON (main_table.entity_id = auit_oit.order_id and auit_oit.parent_item_id IS NULL)
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_prX_status` ON auit_oit.product_id = at_prX_status.entity_id and at_prX_status.attribute_id = 96  and at_prX_status.store_id=main_table.store_id 
 LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `def_at_prX_status` ON auit_oit.product_id = def_at_prX_status.entity_id and def_at_prX_status.attribute_id = 96  and def_at_prX_status.store_id=0 WHERE (`IFNULL(at_prX_status.value, def_at_prX_status.value)` = '1')";i:1;s:6831:"#0 public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
```

I looked into the extension mentioning the 'auit' and checked for any sql statements like

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('`
```

but I couldn't find any.

How else can I solve this? Has anyone ran into this since the patch?

Thanks.

Comment: `IFNULL(at_prX_status.value, def_at_prX_status.value)` has unwanted quotes around it (sadly here used in the editor for highlighting the code). So MySQL thinks it is a column name.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote an str_replace function to remove those to fix it!